# Prevent Normal Request to .ASPX pages When Implemeting URL Routing

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

I am using URL Routing in my .Net Web Application.  I would like to prevent users from being able to access the .aspx page.

Example:

Actual URL - http://www.mysite.com/Testimonials.aspx

Routed URL - http://www.mysite.com/Testimonials

I want users to be able to access the page only by going to `/Testimonials`, but I would like to setup `/Testimonials.aspx` to redirect to its route at `/Testimonials`.

Is there an easy way to do this for Routed Pages throughout the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle the redirect by checking the URL in the Load Event.
Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#adding_routes_to_a_web_forms_application for routing the /Testimonials to the page you want.

Comment: I know how to do the routing... I need help with making sure that the actual page (Testimonials.aspx) cannot be accessed directly.

Comment: if the page load, do something like.  If current url ends with .aspx then check to see if there's a route, if yes, then redirect to the route Url.  Not sure how you would handle parameters like /testimonials/{id}

Comment: Right.  I understand that.  But how do I check if there is a route?